# Trouble enabling Grails logging

Tags: grails, logging

I have this logging configuration in my Config.groovy file.  This is a development environment, started as such.  I have verified the file exists and there are 775 perms on the file, but nothing is getting output to the file.

```
// set per-environment serverURL stem for creating absolute links
environments {
   production {
      grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
   }
   development {
      grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
      logFilePath = "/Users/davea/Tomcat/logs/log4j.log"
   }
   test {
      grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
   }
}

// log4j configuration
log4j = {
   console name:'Appender1',
           layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n')
   rollingFile name:'Appender2', maxFileSize:1024 * 1024, file:logFilePath,
               layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n')
   root {
      debug 'Appender1', 'Appender2'
   }
}
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong with my configuration?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to log on different log levels than DEBUG? here is an example with different logging settings for each environment.

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        // for all environments
        rollingFile name:"file", maxFileSize:(1024*1024), file:"logs\\logfile.log", maxBackupIndex:100
        environments {
            development {
                console name:'stdout'
            }
        }
    }
    // default log level for some loggers
    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate',
            'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

        warn   'org.mortbay.log'

    environments {
        development {
            root {
                debug 'file', 'stdout'
            }
            debug 'grails.app' // <--- maybe you forgot to define this logger for your app!         
        }//development
        test {
            root {
                info 'file'
            }
            info  'grails.app'          
        }
        production {
            root {
                error 'file'
            }
            error'grails.app'           
        }
    }
}
```